# How Do I Cut A Hole In An Image In Corel Draw?

Tags: images, corel-draw

I want to cut a hole out of an image.

When using Corel Draw I want to be able to draw some lines on the image to make a shape, select the inner part of the shape and delete it from the image leaving me with a hole in the image.

I am much more familiar with Flash where I just import an image, break it apart, draw a shape on it and delete the contents of the shape thereby creating a hole in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Although Corel Draw has a good integration with some Raster editing features, the best aproach is:

1. Make a vector shape (the hole)
2. Another vector shape, in this case a rectangle over the photo.
3. Select both and press Ctrl+L (this will combine both into a single object, where you have now a rectangle with a hole.
4. Put your photo inside that object. Power Clip > Put inside.

You aditionally can remove the thickness of the contour.

[image]